# Pop up Window in spring web flow

Tags: jsf, popup, spring-webflow

i am still new to spring.I need to make a popup window when the button is clicked in spring web flow.

Let say in html file

```
 <h:commandLink value="Sick Leave" action="sickleave" id="sickleave" /></div>
```

When the action command link is clicked I have to populate the page with some value on-entry itself.

In my flow.xml

```
    <transition on="sickleave" to="sickLeave"></transition>

    <view-state id="sickLeave" view="sickLeave.xhtml" popup="true"></view-state>
```

i have added popup=true.But still i am not able to get a popup window.

Comment: I don't do Spring Web Flow, but I think you are missing to mention to render popup content on entry. So try adding this in your <view-state> element like this: <on-entry>
        <render fragments="form:popupId" /> where "form:popupId" is the client Id of the popup container.
    </on-entry>

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a to use a **sf:commandLink** component instead of the **h:commandLink** setting the reRender tag as follows:

```
<sf:commandLink value="Sick Leave" action="sickleave" reRender="#{flowRenderFragments}"  processIds="*" id="sickleave" />
```

I'm not sure if the "processIds" tag is needed, so try it with and without it.